# startActivity not working in push handler

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-4.4-kitkat, parse-android-sdk

I am trying to start a new activity when a particular type of push notification is tapped. I've extended `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` class (I'm using Parse) and overridden `onPushOpen` method.

When I tap on the push, the following code does get called:

```
Intent postIntent = new Intent(App.context, SinglePostActivity.class);
postIntent.putExtra(SinglePostActivity.ARG_POST_ID, postId);
context.startActivity(postIntent);
```

But nothing happens. I have my activity registered successfully in AndroidManifest. How can I start the activity successfully?

Comment: @MD As I've explained the question, it's the application context.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: Simply question is: **why not using `context` which is first parameter of `onReceive` or `onPushOpen` method for starting Activity?**

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK didn't see that one. Anyway, switched to that, nothing changed. still not working.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: Also change `Intent postIntent = new Intent(App.context, SinglePostActivity.class);` to `Intent postIntent = new Intent(context, SinglePostActivity.class);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK done. still no difference.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK wait, in the debugger, I've got this: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: Great just add following line `postIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before `context.startActivity(postIntent);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I will, but I want to know its implications. Would it change any crucial behavior?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: No change in behavior this is way to start Activity from ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK okay, thanks. it worked. could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `App.context` causing issue.

Use `Context` parameter of `onPushOpen` method for creating Intent and accessing `startActivity` Activity method :

```
Intent postIntent = new Intent(context, SinglePostActivity.class);
....
postIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(postIntent);
```